# Get the value of a custom membership property umbraco 7 using imember

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to retrieve membership properties using the imember service in Umbraco 7.4, while i can grab the member object i can't see how to call the custom property values. See example below.

```
 // gets the member object successfully 
    var member =  ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetByUsername("myusername");
    member.GetProperty("position"); //not sure how to call this property correctly
```

I can access this property using the old way see code below, but would like to do it correctly.

```
Member m = Member.GetMemberFromEmail("myEmail@hotmail.com");
var Posit = m.getProperty("position").Value;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

ps i'm sure it's in the umbraco documentation, i just couldn't find where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to access properties of the member using the `GetValue<T>` method as follows:

```
var member = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetByUsername("myusername");
var position = member.GetValue<string>("position");
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, exactly what i needed